# Looping in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, associative-array

Oracle PS SQL nested loop:

```
Table 1

key_col start_year End_year
1000    2008       2010
1002    2009       2012
```

For each `key_col` value I want to insert rows by looping through the `start_year` and `end_yea`r for that `key_col`.
For example for `key_col = 1000`, I'd like to insert the following to my target table

```
key_col year
1000    2008
1000    2009
1000    2010
```

How can I do this in PL SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle get numbers with range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045045/oracle-get-numbers-with-range)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the approaches, in which CTE(common table expression) `Years` is used to generate years from min(in this case) 2008 to max 2012 and then right outer join the result with the original data.

```
   with years(yr) as(
      select min_year + (level - 1)
        from ( select min(start_year) as min_year
                    , max(end_year)   as max_year
                 from your_table) t
              connect by min_year + (level - 1) <= t.max_year
             )
    select s.key_col
         , s.yr
      from ( select *
               from your_table yt
              right join years y
                 on (y.yr >= yt.start_year and 
                     y.yr <= yt.end_year)
            ) s
     order by key_col
            , yr
```

result:

```
   KEY_COL         YR
---------- ----------
      1000       2008
      1000       2009
      1000       2010
      1002       2009
      1002       2010
      1002       2011
      1002       2012
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2011a/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select key_col, start_year+rn as year 
from table1,
(select level-1 as rn from dual connect by level<100) a
 where rn <= end_year - start_year
 order by 1,2
```

Result

```
KEY_COL     YEAR
1000        2008
1000        2009
1000        2010
1002        2009
1002        2010
1002        2011
1002        2012
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
BEGIN
   FOR RECORD IN (SELECT KEY_COL,START_YEAR,END_YEAR FROM TABLE1)--Loop records in table 1
   LOOP
      FOR YEAR IN RECORD.START_YEAR .. RECORD.END_YEAR --Loop from start to end years
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RECORD.KEY_COL||' - '||YEAR);--Show values for testing
         INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (KEY_COL,YEAR) VALUES (RECORD.KEY_COL,YEAR);-- Insert
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```