# Oracle get numbers with range

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is my serial table:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
|  START_SERIAL   |   END_SERIAL    |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| 120500216057150 | 120500216057155 |
| 120500216057157 | 120500216057157 |
| 120500216057161 | 120500216057164 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Need to get result like this:

```
120500216057150 
120500216057151 
120500216057152 
120500216057153 
120500216057154 
120500216057155
120500216057157
120500216057161....
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.
[seems need pl-sql with for loop needed.?]

**EDIT**
dear TechDo,
What about pl/sql usage here as follows.but its gives me a error :-)

```
DECLARE
  start_serial  NUMBER;
  end_serial  NUMBER;
  records NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select start_serial INTO start_serial
    from sales_details ;
  select (start_serial+no_of_cards)as end_serial into end_serial
    from sales_details;
  select count(*) as records into records 
    from sales_details;

  FOR i IN 1..records  LOOP
    INSERT INTO temp (serial_no)
    VALUES(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: @Actually you need a for loop approach for this problem?

Comment: how is the answer whn pl-sql added.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
  distinct START_SERIAL+level-1 SERIAL
from 
  YourTable
connect by level-1<=END_SERIAL-START_SERIAL
order by 1;
```

Comment: many thanks dear TechDo
now its sorted.wt abt pl-sql usage for that question.?

Comment: +1 for the simplicity. @TechDo Just a curiosity, why `dual` table?

Comment: Please check http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540661/why-does-connect-by-level-on-a-table-return-extra-rows

Comment: There is absolutely no need to cross join `YourTable` with `dual`. Why are you doing this? By doing this you are just adding one `nested loop` to the execution plan and increasing, however insignificant it can be, the overall cost of a query.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Please add the solution. It will be helpful for all.